# Uploading photo to Facebook using Graph API

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-studio

I am developing a simple android app to post to facebook and twitter.
So far , i have succeeded in posting simple status updates and tweets.
Now i need to post a photo along with the status. I am new to Android development and i am unable to figure out how to upload a photo.

This is the code i used to update facebook status. Can someone please modify this to upload a photo from an ImageView?

```
public void postToFacebook(){

    final EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);

    if (isFacebookAuthed()){

        String path = "me/feed";
        AccessToken at = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", message.getText().toString());
        HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.POST;
        GraphRequest.Callback cb = new GraphRequest.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                //check graphResponse for success or failure
                if(graphResponse.getError()==null){
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Successfully posted to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Facebook: There was an error, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        };

        GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(at,path,parameters,method,cb);
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();


    }
    else
    {

        Toast.makeText(Home.this,"You are not logged into Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Note: isFacebookAuhed() is a boolean method which returns true if the user has logged in to facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below parameter to post photo on facebook.

You need to convert your image into byte array.

```
parameters.putByteArray("picture", bytearray);
```

Comment: thanks! it worked!
also i had to change the path to "me/photos"

Comment: Yes me will upload photo to your profile the person's email id with whom you have logged in with facebook.You can also upload photo to particular facebook page by passing page id in place of me.

Comment: that is not worked for me. I am giving this error in facebook graph response : "picture is not properly formatted"

Answer (score 0):

How about the [SharePhotoContent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/SharePhotoContent)?

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path); // From file or memory
 SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
 SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();
 ShareDialog dialog = new ShareDialog(this);   // this is current activity
 dialog.show(content);
```

And of course you need to be authorized by `logInWithPublishPermissions` with `"publish_actions"` before call the `ShareDialog.show()`.

Comment: i dont want to switch to facebook app or show facebook share dialog. i want to post directly from my app. thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
                   // params.putString("multipart/form-data", imgurl);
                    params.putByteArray("multipart/form-data",byteArray);

                    params.putString("caption", txtcaption.getText().toString());
                    /* make the API call */
                    new GraphRequest(
                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                            "/me/photos",
                            params,
                            HttpMethod.POST,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                    /* handle the result */
                                    Log.e("responseImagedata---", response.toString());

                                }
                            }`enter code here`
                    ).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public void postToFacebook(){

        final EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
         /*   Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ll);
             ByteArrayOutputStream blob1=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                     image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,0,blob1);
            byte[] bitmapdata = blob1.toByteArray();*/
            Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ll);
            ByteArrayOutputStream blob=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,0,blob);
            byte[] bitmapdata=blob.toByteArray();
            String path = "me/feed";
            AccessToken at = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
           parameters.putByteArray("image",bitmapdata);
            parameters.putString("message", message.getText().toString());
            HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.POST;
            GraphRequest.Callback cb = new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                    //check graphResponse for success or failure
                    if(graphResponse.getError()==null){
                        Toast.makeText(AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.this, "Successfully posted to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.this, "Facebook: There was an error, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            };

            GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(at,path,parameters,method,cb);
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();


        }
        else
        {

            Toast.makeText(AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.this,"You are not logged into Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```